# Presenting a different view on WebDAV depending on user

Tags: apache-2.4, webdav

How can I configure Apache to allow multiple users to connect to a WebDAV share using the same URL (`https://server/webdav/`), while ensuring that each user sees the directory as if they were the only one connecting? I attempted to use `Alias /webdav /var/www/html/webdav/%{REMOTE_USER}`, but it appears that variables are not expanded in that context. Additionally, I would like to avoid using redirection if possible. The current configuration currently boils down to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /webdav /var/www/html/webdav/%{REMOTE_USER}

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Dav On
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```